# How to separate multiple data frames in pd.read_html() when saving to excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to save data from multiple tables brought in through `pd.read_html()`. If I print `df`, I can see it captured all the data, but when saving the data it is only saving the first table to excel. How do I separate out the tables so I can save each one to a separate sheet in excel (i.e. Quarterly Income Statement on sheet1, Annual Income Statement on sheet2, etc.). Below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
dfs = pd.read_html(https://www.google.com/finance?q=googl&fstype=ii, flavor='html5lib')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output.xlsx, engine='xlsxwriter')
for df in dfs:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you will probably have to change `sheet_name` with each iteration in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate on your list and flush them to a new sheet of the same workbook

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance?q=googl&fstype=ii', flavor='html5lib')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer.
xlWriter = pd.ExcelWriter('myworkbook.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each df to its own sheet
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_excel(xlWriter, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))

# Close the writer and output the Excel file (mandatory!)
xlWriter.save()
```

Comment: almost per character the same as what I was about to post :-)

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you! When doing it this way, can I still format the names of the worksheets in python or do I lose that functionality?

Comment: Just replace `sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i)` with whatever you see fit.